# Determine if a given subset is a subspace of a given vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> The set of all polynomials of degree greater than $3$ together with the zero polynomial in the vector space $P$ of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$

I don't really understand the wording here.

So are they asking me to show whether $P_k, k\ge 4$ is a subspace of $P$, or not?

Well this is true, since $(P_k, k\ge 2)\subset P$, but my book tells me it is not a subspace, so I think I am misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the properties for a subspace?

The set you're given consists of all polynomials of degree $>3$ together with zero. So, for instance, $x^2$ doesn't belong to it.

Hint: what about $(x^4+1)-(x^4-x^2+1)$?

Comment: Interesting. Two polynomials in the set, but their sum is not

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I concluded directly an answer because I saw the subset relation

Comment: @KSplitX Right so.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$p(X)=1+X +X^4$ and $q(X)=-X-X^4$ belong to the set.  Does $p(X)+q(X)$ belong to this set?